# rsync for copying file

Tags: rsync, migration

I am migrating my old server to new server . I used this server for hosting website . first I tried sftp but due to huge number of files and connection time out , it simply didn't work .
then I tried rsync .rsync working good , but only problem I am facing it updating file very nicely & fastly but do not copy new files 
please help me . because still i need to transfer lots of file.
I am using this command :
 rsync -anv -e ssh oldserver:/path/ /path

Comment: could you give more information. Is it identical hardware/software? What operating system is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-n` means 'dry run', as in, no files are actually copied.

Comment: seriously , lemme try , such a silly mistake i was doing